# Removing symbol link with too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, linux-mint, symbolic-link, rm

I created a link by the command

```
 sudo ln -s /etc/Sublime\ Text/ /usr/bin/subl
```

Now I am trying to remove it with

```
sudo rm -r /usr/bin/subl/
```

But it is telling me

```
rm: cannot remove `/usr/bin/subl': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I have tried `-rf` but that didn't help. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from your command:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/bin/subl
```